# Grouped Bar plot for categorical variables in r

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have plotted the group bar plot but it does not show much. This is the coding I used.

```
      library(ggplot2)
      >  #grouped
      >  df_new2 %>% mutate(Race=as.factor(Race)) %>% group_by(Year,Race) %>% 
      summarize(mean=mean(Life_expectancy)) %>% ggplot() +
      +    aes(x=Year, y=mean, group=Race, col=Race) +
      +    geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
      +    labs(title="Life expectancy by race from 2015-2021", x="Year", y="Mean of 
      life 
      expectancy")
```

[image: grouped bar plot]

I also made a line graph.
[image: line graph]

This is the coding I used:

```
   > df_new2 %>% mutate(Gender=as.factor(Race)) %>% group_by(Year,Race) %>% 
  summarize(mean=mean(Life_expectancy)) %>% ggplot() +
  +   aes(x=Year, y=mean, group=Race, col=Race) +
  +   geom_line()+
  +   labs(title="Life expectancy by Race from 2015-2021", x="Year", y="Mean of life 
  expectancy")
```

My question is, What can I do to make my graph better? I really need the experts' help because I need to do last-minute modifications to my graph before my presentation on Monday.

Comment: For the bar chart, you can use `fill = as.character(Race)` instead of `col = Race`. For the line graph, use `col = as.character(Race)`. Everything else is just theming. My preference is to add `+ theme_minimal()` to most plots.

Comment: @AllanCameron has good advice. You could also use `factor` labels for your `Race` variable instead of 0, 1, 2. Have you seen this page? http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-barplots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization